# Apex DateTime formatting for Dynamic SOQL query returning wrong value

Tags: apex, soql, datetime

I am passing a DateTime as a Long into my Apex controller and storing it in a variable called start, and it has a value of:

```
1528329130300
```

When I create a DateTime from the Long

```
DateTime startDateTime = DateTime.newInstance(start);
System.debug('startDateTime: ' + startDateTime);
```

I get the expected output:

```
startDateTime: 2018-06-06 23:52:10
```

But when I format it for use in a Dymanic SOQL query like this:

```
startDateTime.format('yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'hh:mm:ss\'Z\'')
```

I get a different **day** and **time**:

```
2018-06-07T12:52:10Z
```

I am using this DateTime to query and the difference in value is leaving out records I am expecting to get.

What am I doing wrong with the DateTime formatting?

Comment: The latter output is the format you *need* for SOQL. Why do you think you are doing anything wrong? Are you having trouble running the query?

Comment: I understand the format is what I need for SOQL, but the actual day and time returns from the formatting is different by 12 hours. Which means I don't get the expected result from the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the correct value formatted as a String for the Dynamic SOQL Query, I needed to use this:

```
startDateTime.formatGMT('yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'HH:mm:ss\'Z\'')
```

Note:

1) the use of `DateTime.formatGMT(format);` as Adrian Larson suggested

and

2) the hour needed to be `HH` rather than `hh`

---

Apex code used to debug:

```
TimeZone tz = UserInfo.getTimeZone();
System.debug('String format: ' + tz.toString());
System.debug('Display name: ' + tz.getDisplayName());
Long start = Long.valueOf('1528329130300');
System.debug('start: ' + start);
DateTime startDateTime = DateTime.newInstance(start);
System.debug('startDateTime: ' + startDateTime);
System.debug('Offset: ' + tz.getOffset(startDateTime));
System.debug('startDateTime: ' + startDateTime.formatGMT('yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'HH:mm:ss\'Z\''));
```

Answer (score 3):

You can format the `Datetime` instance according to `GMT`:

```
String correctTimeZoneValue = DateTime.newInstance(myLong).formatGMT(myFormat);
```

Comment: So I should be doing `startDateTime.formatGMT('yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'hh:mm:ss\'Z\'')`

Comment: @Robs Yes. Or you might have to do `Datetime.newInstanceGmt(start)`. Try both.

Comment: `DateTime.newInstanceGmt` does not take a Long, and `startDateTime.formatGMT('yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'hh:mm:ss\'Z\'')` does not return the correct value

Comment: The values you have provided indicate you have a GMT offset of +11. So using `formatGmt` should account for that and give you the correct hour. Surely the output is different? What is the new offset?

Comment: I am not setting an offset. The org has a default timezone of (GMT+01:00) British Summer Time (Europe/London).